# What value does a Pointer to a Pointer print if not a single dereference operator is used at all?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I have tried the output of the following code. But, i don't yet understand what might the value of q represent.

I understand that the *q points to p implying that, printing *q would print the address of p, where as **q would print the value at the address p points to, i.e., x(=5).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=5;
    int *p,**q;
    p=&x;
    q=&p;
    cout<<q;
    return 0;
}
```

So what does q alone represent? What is that value that is printed when just q is printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> printing *q would print the address of p

However this is not true. Printing `q` would print the address of `p`. After all, you assigned that in doing `q = &p;`.

Printing `*q` would print the value of `p` , which is the address of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Just print value and ardess of your variable and you will see:

```
   x: 5                     &x: 0x7fff691dfcc4
   p: 0x7fff691dfcc4        &p: 0x7fff691dfcb8
   q: 0x7fff691dfcb8        &q: 0x7fff691dfcb0

&var - location; 
 var - value
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `q` is a pointer to `p`, the value of `q` is the location of `p`, whatever that means on this particular platform. (Most likely the memory address containing `p`'s value.)

Answer (score 1):

(I will assume 64-bit pointers and 32-bit integers in this answer, just to have concrete values to write about. It holds with any vaues, though).

Let's analyse `p` first. `p` is 8 bytes storing an address (of the variable `x`). Printing `*p` will print the value residing at that address, which is the 4 bytes of the value of variable `x`. Printing just `p` will print the 8 bytes of the address stored in `p`.

Now, the same applies to `q`. `q` is 8 bytes storing an address of the variable `p`. So printing `*p` will print the value residing at that address, which is the 8 bytes of the value of `p`. Printing just `q` will print the 8 bytes of the address stored in `q`.

Answer (score 1):

int x = 1;

A block of memory is allocated to hold int value. And that block is named as 'x'. Let's say x is allocated at 0x1234.

int *p;

Here 'p' is pointer to int that means p would contain the address of some int. Let's say p is allocated address 0x2345.

```
p = &x;
```

This would make p contain the address of x i.e 0x1234 would be stored in the location allotted to p.

```
int **q;
```

Here q is pointer to pointer to an int that means q would contain the address of pointer to int. Let's say q is allotted address 0x3456.

```
q = &p;
```

This would make q contain the address of p i.e 0x2345 would be stored in the location allotted to q.

Hope I am simple and clear...

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is just a data type, being not very different from other types.
It stores an address of another data object, and you can use *p to access the data object.
So, pointers are not different from other types but their contents have some special meaning.

(int**) is such a pointer that points to a data object of type (int*), being not very different from other pointers (they may point to data object of type int).

So, the content of q is a pointer to p. *q indicates you use the content to find p.
the content of p is a pointer to an Integer, *p indicates you use the content to find the integer.

Answer (score 1):

By adding ** before q in declaration of q, you are saying to compiler that, q is a pointer which will point to address of a pointer. So when you are printing q, you are actually printing address of p pointer, not the value of address p point to (i.e. x).

In your code, p is a pointer which is storing an address of an integer. But p itself has an address, which you are storing in q.